# How to debug on intellij idea for leiningen

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, ioexception, leiningen

I installed　leiningen in IntelliJ IDEA, 
then I click View >> Tool Windows >> Leiningen ,

In the Leiningen menu, I click  `add leiningen file`, 
choose `/home/l/test/project.clj`
and Run `Leiningen build`,
but get the error

> "Error running Leiningen: Cannot run program "/please/set/me/up/in/settings/leiningen" (in directory "/home/l/test"): java.io.IOException: error=2"

How do I debug the error?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings (ctrl+alt+s) > Leiningen` and set `Leiningen executable` to the location of the lein executable on your machine.